# Facial emotion recognition on cartoon images

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, detection

I'm new to deep learning and I'm working on a project that involves working on cartoon images and recognizing the emotions of the cartoon characters, I tried the approach of transfer learning but on doing some research I realised that the ImageNet and InceptionV3 only work for human faces. What approach should I follow? The training set is limited of about 300 images and the test set has around 180 images. I'm still a beginner in this field and I thought this would be a good project to start with. Any suggestions/guidance will be much appreciated. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

If your data is very low you can use data augmentation.Take a look:

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-deep-learning-4fe21d1a4eb9

and also:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-image-data-augmentation-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/

---

> If data augmentation did not help you, you must try another
>   algorithms.neural nets needs lots of data.If your Data is less your
>   network will overfitt.

---

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I wanted to know can I use CNN for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use data augmentation. for data augmentation, you could use the imgaug package. here is the documentation of [Imgaug package](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)